# C# Program displaying "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

Tags: c#, rest, api

I am having an issue with getting connected to the remote server:

**The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.**

Below is almost the complete code I am using for my program. I want to grab data from the API, but the server won't authenticate properly. I know there is a way to add the credentials you like, but I have tried every which way possible with adding it in. Not sure where I need to plug that at, so I can make a connection.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace RestClient
{
    public enum httpVerb
    {
        GET,
        POST,
        PUT,
        DELETE,
    }

    class RestClient
    {
        public string endPoint { get; set; }
        public httpVerb httpMethod { get; set; }

        public RestClient()
        {
            endPoint = string.Empty;
            httpMethod = httpVerb.GET;
        }

        public string makeRequest()
        {
            string strResponseVlaue = string.Empty;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPoint);
            request.Method = httpMethod.ToString();

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("Error Code: "+ response.StatusCode.ToString());
                }
                //Process the response stream

            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if(responseStream != null)
                    {
                        using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            strResponseVlaue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                } //End of Response Stream
            }// End Of Using Reponse

                return strResponseVlaue;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Jimmy Dean

Edit:

```
myReq.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
myReq.PreAuthenticate = true;
myReq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

For the questions that have been asked. I was trying to use this and some others I tried. The code is fine, it is just not authorizing the connection, that is the issue I am having.

Comment: so where are you trying to add the actual credentials ?

Comment: Everything here looks fine, what you aren't showing or saying is what the authentication method should be?

Comment: myReq.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
myReq.PreAuthenticate = true;
myReq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

Comment: The server is using Windows Authentication?  What user is this process running under?

Comment: Domain admin account @JimW

Comment: Check this out: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enable-windows-authentication-in-web-api-and-angular-app/